# How to load a view when the app becomes active again in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I want to open a certain view when my app becomes active again. In my appDelegate file i have this

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    print("ACTIVATE!")
}
```

This works fine but I don’t know how to call or what to call to open the view I want. The view I want to open is called “StartUpLoginPage”

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this

```
  func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    //open the login page to do the updating of the user infomration
    print("ACTIVATE!")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(loginPage)
    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
}
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: That's nice but you do realize that you've killed the whole rest of your interface, right? Whatever view controllers were there before have been blown away.

Comment: Isn't it causing a memory leak?

Comment: @matt yes that is what I wanted to do. I basically wanted a reset of the app when I entered into it again.

Comment: @MirekE Not a clue. Doesn't seam to be giving me any issues right now

Comment: Okay, that's fine. Just making sure! :)

Comment: @MirekE I don't think this will cause a memory leak, when the rootController is changed, all the existing viewControllers are deallocated